# Neo4j, Cypher: Set avg rating of a director on the basis of his/her movies

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Unable to write a query to set avg rating for a director.

Also, can't figure out how to use `FOREACH` in this case to avoid `Invalid use of aggregating function` , `Type mismatch: expected Collection<T> but was Node` errors.

Avg Rating of a director = Avg(Rating of all its movies)

Example query

```
MATCH (d:Director)
WITH d
MATCH (d)-[:Directed]->(m:Movie)
SET d.avg_rating = AVG(toFloat(COLLECT(m.rating)))
```

Please help out.

Comment: Add Your requirement clear,
also 
SET a.avg_rating = AVG(toFloat(COLLECT(b.total_weight)))
Here b is not defined anywhere in the query.
Add details about your structure and your requirement

Comment: Updated. Sorry for these errors.

Comment: That's detailed enough

Answer (score 2):

The toFloat would apply directly to m.rating, and AVG doesn't need the COLLECT:

```
MATCH (d:Director)-[:Directed]->(m:Movie)
SET d.avg_rating = AVG(toFloat(m.rating))
```

(I also dropped the superfluous match d:Director, which has nothing to do with your error however)

Answer (score 2):

You Can directly use

```
MATCH (d:Director)-[:Directed]->(m:Movie)
SET d.avg_rating = AVG(toFloat(m.rating))
```